# loop to paste only on rows with data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Can anyone help me to modify this loop to copy and paste?

I want to paste `Range("S" & Y).Select`  in the same row only if there is data in the form of time, date, or n/a in `Range("F" & Y)`. I want to repeat this until the last data point in `Range("F" & Y)`. I there is now data on the row in `Range("F" & Y)`  then it shouldn’t paste `Range("S" & Y)` . When there is data in `Range("F" & Y)` it show up every three lines. Sometime there is a gap in the data maybe 10 lines until the next data sequence which returns to every three rows.

**Error**: it doesn’t stop at the end of that dataset and it paste even when there is no data in `Range("F" & Y)`  Can anyone help?

My  code

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Range("S16:Y16").Select
Selection.Copy
For Y = 19 To 2000 Step 3

    If Range("F" & Y).Value = lastRow Then Exit For
    Range("S" & Y).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Next Y
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox lastRow
```

Comment: If you chexk for blank `range("F" & Y).value` do you need to skip to every third row?

Comment: can you tell us why you want to step in threes skipping rows?

Comment: if you have it working, please choose an answer **ON ALL YOUR QUESTIONS**

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

1. First thing is it doesn't stop at the end when the `lastRow` is greater than 2000 and your `if` statement isn't checking for the current row number just the value in it. Also there is a great chance you skip this last row because you are jumping by 3 rows at a time. I suggest you use the following `if` statement instead:

   ```
   If Range("F" & Y).row > lastRow Then Exit For
   ```
2. For your `lastrow` variable I suggest the following to be more accurate:

   ```
   lastrow = activesheet.cells.find("*", range("A1"), , , xlbyrows, xlprevious).row
   ```
3. Also, you're pasting data in every row without checking for a blank value and I would check for a blank cell using this:

   ```
   if len(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(trim(range("F" & Y).value))) > 0 then
   ```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could do this with a Worksheet formula in Columns S to Y as below:

```
=IF($F:$F<>"",S:S,"")
```

copy that formula accross from columns S to Y, then down to 2000.

To check if the ROW is every third row, use the ROW() function to get the row number, and use MOD to see if it's divisible by 3 perhaps?

for VBA, try this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("S16:Y16").Copy
For Y = lastRow to 19 Step -3
' check column F and Row=Y for contents
if vba.len(vba.trim(range("F" & Y).value))>0 then  
    ' paste into column S
    Range("S" & Y).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
end if 
Next 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox lastRow
```

Now it will run BACKWARDS from lastRow to 19

your code was checking the value of the cells Range("F" & Y) or Cells(y,6) against the number of the last row

Comment: I got a compile error next without for. I dont understand. Stopped at Next Y

Comment: sorry, missed an *End If*, please try it now

Comment: Thanks for your help. The msg Last row is 1355 but it stopped at 1321.... It stopped once before where the space between was data set was 4 not 3 but that shouldn't matter so I deleted a row and ran it again. Still didnt go to the last data row it missed 5 files. Any ideas.

Comment: try it now, it will run backwards from lastRow to row=19, skipping 3 rows eact iteration of the loop. BTW, you could check the test **if vba.len(vba.trim(range("F" & Y).value))>0** is working correctly for the rows that are being missed using *Debug.print vba.trim(range("F" & Y).value* inside your loop?

Comment: I am sorry I am not very good at this but I am learning. I want to learn to understand it better. I ran it again but it didnt go in reverse. I also change out the data from those cells and row and it wouldnt go to the end of the data set. How do I do the test?

Comment: 1) is it working ok? amd 2) don't be sorry, it's great that you are trying to learn or improve and asking sensible questions!

Comment: it works great up to 4 rows before the last data set. It doesnt paste for them.

Comment: 1354 isnt the last data set 1364 is. So its not counting correcting. FYI. I checked the cell format and its the same as the others

Comment: your best bet is to step through the code (use **F8**) watching what it does to see what rows it is stepping over. Also, try outputting the value of *vba.trim(range("F" & Y).value* to the Immedtaie window inside your loop, then you can check that too

Comment: Step through
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("S16:Y16").Copy
For Y = lastRow To 19 Step 3
‘Skips everything in the middle doesn’t loop 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox lastRow
End Sub
Then message box says 1354  - it should go through the loop process correct

Comment: please check the value of lastRow after this line: **lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row** is column B the right column to check for the last row?

Comment: Hey Philip I created a new wk sheet with new data. It still wont go to end of the data row. NOT sure where to go from here. Can I upload or send you the sheet. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: it is skipping the last couple of rows because it is stepping through the rows in threes (`For Y = lastRow to 19 Step -3`)

Comment: if you have it working, please choose an answer **ON ALL YOUR QUESTIONS**